# How to reference S3 bucket created in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have created an S3 bucket in serverless in cloudformation as follows:

```
    s3bucket:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref 's3bucket'
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: ProdAnsiblePolicy
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: 'arn:aws:iam::*******:user/prodAnsible'
              Action: 's3:*'
              Resource:
                - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 's3bucket']]
```

Now I would like to reference this bucket in a lambda event as seen in the [serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/). To be clear, I need to create this S3 bucket in the cloud formation so that I can give access to the prodAnsible user.

This is how I have tried to reference it in the lambda:

```
  update_tenant_config:
    handler: functions/tenants_handlers.update_tenant_config
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: s3bucket
          event: s3:ObjectRemoved:*
          existing: true
```

Thanks for your assistance in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this config? what's the error?

Comment: To clarify: Are you saying that you create the bucket in a CloudFormation stack, and then you wan to reference that bucket from an AWS Lambda function? Is the Lambda function created as part of the same stack, or is it totally independent?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is this. I wanted to create the bucket in cloud formation so I could add a policy. Then I simply want to trigger a lambda when an object is put into the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

In cloud formation you can add a BucketName property, which can be referenced outside of cloudformation.

```
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${opt:stage}-your-bucket-name
```

Comment: The issue is it also tries to add when you reference on event.